# Convex subsets of pinched Hadamard manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry

Let $X$ be a pinched Hadamard manifold (in my particular case, $X=\mathbb H^n$ is the $n$-dim. hyperbolic space) and $N$ be a closed (**edit** : open) convex subset of $X$.

Is it true that $N$ is also a pinched Hadamard manifold ?

Comment: What is your definition of a pinched Hadamard manifold? Is it required to be a Riemannian manifold? Then convex subsets of $H^n$ are, typically, not smooth manifolds.

Comment: Yes, it is required to be a Riemannian manifold. So, you're right and I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a Riemannian manifold with the same curvature bounds as the original one; in the case of interest, of constant curvature $-1$. It is also dimply connected. However, most (if not all) definitions require Hadamard manifolds to be complete and in your case open convex subsets are hardly ever  complete.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for this answer.